# HoloLens websockets

Tags: websocket, hololens

I'm trying to program a websocket client for the HoloLens using `System.Net.Sockets;`.
It works in Unity but when I try to build it for the HoloLens I get errors like:

```
Socket does not contain a definition of Connect
```

The websocket libraries for Unity also don't work.
How can I create a websocket client for the HoloLens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you will need to use [websockets for UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets) for the hololens and use `System.Net.Sockets` for the Unity Editor and [wrap the UWP code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-scripts.html) in `NETFX_CORE` or `WINDOWS_UWP` define.

Comment: Can I also just use the UWP code? I dont have to use sockets in the editor. Or am I asked something weird?

Comment: Yes you can just use the UWP code. It then only works on the hololens.

Comment: Thanks I will try it now

Comment: Thanks it works. But on another note, do you know how to connect to either localhost or a pc on a local area network with the hololens emulator?

Comment: @J.Daniel do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) unity object to send and receive http requests/answers! I had no problem connecting with http protocol with the hololens using this.

Comment: Http is not websockets

Comment: This is confirmed working on Hololens? I am interested in using this functionality and I want to make sure that it works.

Comment: If you want to play ping pong with your server, yes it works. You start a coroutine and yield to the www object, you can then check the answer and use it!

Comment: @mTheZ, do you have an example of this working?  I've been having trouble trying to do anything with this.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to that code anymore... it should normally work easily. Check that your url is ok?